# ImportError: cannot import name 'easy_word_set' from 'textstat.textstat'

Tags: python, pip, importerror

```
import spacy
import codecs 
from textstat.textstat import textstatistics, easy_word_set
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'easy_word_set' from 'textstat.textstat' (c:\users\xxx xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\textstat\textstat.py)
```

I found that very strange, for I have pip install all the modules spacy and textstat, I don't know why the error occurred, can someone help with that problem ?

Comment: Make sure that the version of that package that you're using is exposing that attribute. The author might have updated the package to remove/rename it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the problem is my classmates using the same coding can import the "easy_word_set", and I can not. I have upgraded it but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

from [`textstat.textstat`](https://github.com/shivam5992/textstat/blob/master/textstat/textstat.py) you can only import variable `langs`, functions `legacy_round` and `get_grade_suffix`, class `textstatistics` and its instance `textstat`. The name `easy_word_set` is a name of a few internal variables and cannot be imported.

The method `__get_lang_easy_words` seems to return its value so you need to import `textstat` and call `textstat._textstatistics__get_lang_easy_words()` (the method is private with leading double underscores so you need to call it specially).